# How to get callback information on how many notifications sent to which user?

Tags: azure-notificationhub, azure-node-sdk

I am using Azure Notification Hub for sending mobile notification from Node.js. I am using Tags when I send Notification, I need to store how many users received notification. But in the callback, I am not getting any information.

Is there any way to get this information?

Comment: What SDK are you using?

Comment: I am using npm azure SDK

Answer (score 0):

What Billing subscription are you using for Azure Notification Hubs? Only the standard billing tier provides detailed telemetry.

All Azure Notification Hubs is going to know is that the PNS accepted the notification. You should update your client application to send results to the backend application when the notification arrives on device.